# Sending a Message to Multiple Clients from One Server Simultaneously?

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I am currently working on a TCP Sockets program in Java in which two or more separate clients connect to a single server, and that server will send a message to both of these connected clients simultaneously.

I've tried to work through the code multiple times, but I can't quite seem to be able to have one message be sent to both clients.

Below is a reduced version of my entire code, condensed down to just the issue I'm having.

I've also included a video, just to save you the effort of having to copy and run my code!
[[STREAMABLE LINK]](https://streamable.com/5r7ar9)

When one client is connected, I just have to write one message in the server, press send, and it shows up in the client.
When two clients are connected, I have to write two messages in the server and press send twice, and one message goes to one client and the other to the next client.

How can I make it so I only send **one message** from the server that goes to **all clients**?

I greatly appreciate any and all help.

**SERVER CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
  
// Server class
class Server {

    public class countLogic {
        public static int client_count = 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("[SERVER]");
        ServerSocket server = null;
  
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(1234);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);

            while (true) {
  
                Socket client = server.accept();
                countLogic.client_count++;
  
                System.out.println("Client ("+countLogic.client_count+") connected: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
  
                ClientHandler clientSock = new ClientHandler(client);
  
                new Thread(clientSock).start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  
    // ClientHandler class
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;
  
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }
  
        public void run()
        {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                    
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  
                String line = null;
                while (true) {
                    line = sc.nextLine();
                    out.println(line);
                    
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
  
// Client class
class Client {
    
    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("[CLIENT 1]");

        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234)) {
            
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream(), true);
  
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = null;
  
            while (!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                

                System.out.println("Server: "+ in.readLine());
            }
            
            // closing the scanner object
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing data input in the individual Thread, if you want to send for all Threads?

Comment: That's a great question which I don't have an answer to unfortunately!
I'm pretty new to Java and the concept of threads, so I wasn't even aware I was making such an error. 
Where/what should I move in order to remedy the issue I'm having?

Comment: Maybe do something like, in your while loop accept new connections, and store the `Socket` in an array.  Have another read that will take your input and write to this Array of Sockets.  Only two Threads needed I think.

Comment: That sounds perfect. 
 Thank you a ton for your help!